# How to turn on monitor Raspbian/Raspberry using ssh?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry/Raspbian, connected to a monitor using hdmi/dvi.

It's possible to power On this Monitor (when is off)?

My monitor does not support CEC. However, Tvservice is working.

```
tvservice -o
```

But only disable the hdmi, for example it's good if I want to stand by the TV. 
But if I have the Monitor OFF and I want to power On via ssh, I can't found any compatible command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a raspberry with a tv and a pc monitor.
I can turn both off with `tvservice -o`, and to turn them on I use:

```
tvservice -p; fbset -depth 8; fbset -depth 16
```

Comment: Use capitals and punctuation, if you want long live here.